# Chrome Webstore search API (inspect webstore requests failed)

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app, chrome-web-store, webstore

I've been looking for an API that gives me Chrome WebStore search result. 
I send a query, and it returns the search result elements (apps/extensions).

I couldn't find anything like this.

**EDIT**

As **wOxxOm** said, I tried to inspect the requests made by webstore page. When I try to curl the url `https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/game?hl=en_US`, I get the initial page as response, even if `game` is my search query.
And when I try to curl `https://chrome.google.com/webstore/ajax/item?....` I get an error message, because there are some parameters I need to send that may be there exactly to block what I'm trying to do.
So, is it impossible? Where can I send questions directly to Google Chrome Team?

Thank you!

Comment: Inspect the requests made by webstore page in devtools network panel when you search for something (the results are json-serialized) and try to replicate it in your extension. But I think your extension won't be allowed in  the webstore as this activity is effectively reverse-engineering.